# inverting a percentage (basically inverting the percentages in pie chart)

Tags: inverse, fractions, inverse-function, percentages

This is a weird question and I am not sure if it makes sense.
Say we have 4 distances (where these are 1 dimensional distances):

```
5
3
8
6
```

so the total distance => `SUM(5,3,8,6)` = 22.

So for the first distance, it represents 3/22 of the total distance, which could be converted to a percent. But in my case, the shortest distance actually means a higher percentage, and a longer distance means a lower percentage.

Originally percentages would be:

```
(5/22)*100
(3/22)*100
(8/22)*100
(6/22)*100
```

Is there a way to invert this somehow mathematically, so that a smaller fraction means a bigger percent, something like:

```
(22/5)/100
(22/3)/100
(22/8)/100
(22/6)/100
```

however, this is not right, since there is an obvious smell, in the case of 22/x being bigger than 100. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a unique way to do this. For instance, you can consider the "remaining" distance:
$$5 \quad\longrightarrow\quad 22-5=17 \quad\longrightarrow\quad \frac{17}{66}\cdot 100 = 25.76\%,$$
$$3 \quad\longrightarrow\quad 22-3=19 \quad\longrightarrow\quad \frac{19}{66}\cdot 100 = 28.78\%,$$
$$8 \quad\longrightarrow\quad 22-8=14 \quad\longrightarrow\quad \frac{14}{66}\cdot 100 = 21.21\%,$$
$$6 \quad\longrightarrow\quad 22-6=16 \quad\longrightarrow\quad \frac{16}{66}\cdot 100 = 24.24\%,$$
where $66=17+19+14+16$.

Comment: this makes sense off the bat, thanks

Comment: looks good, i wonder if there is another way of doing that doesn't involve subtraction or addition, more of a modeling question